# How to upgrade Linq to SQL dbml file from old version of VS?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I opened an old project, and I can't open the dbml file.

For some reason I get "Cannot load.. check Error List window for details".

But, there aren't any errors.

I can create new dbml file, so there is no problem in the viewer itself.

Is there a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would check is the **connection string** of the dbml file, which you can find in the `FileName.designer.cs` (or could be .vb instead of .cs)  file that is attached to the `FileName.dbml` file.

If you say you *can* create a new dbml file, then it is possible that the old dbml file has an outdated connection string.